# How to email contact forms?

Tags: php, html, email

I'm looking for a way I can set my drop-down list to send an email to that specific person after clicking on their name. Basically the php code emailto will change to the persons email address that was selected in the drop-down list.

I don't know how to do it, but this is for a project, and I thought it would be cool, if I could use it, if it's even possible.

All-In-All I'm asking if anyone knows a code I can use to complete this task. As of now the drop-down list `<li>` is set to `<a href>`. Code below:

```
<form action="Test.php" method="post" class="popup-form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-white" maxlength="25" name="first_name" placeholder="Name">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-white" maxlength="25" name="last_name" placeholder="Name">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-white" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-white" maxlength="11" name="telephone" placeholder="Name">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-white" name="comments" placeholder="Message">

                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button id="dLabel" class="form-control form-white dropdown" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Contact
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeIn" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                        <li class="animated lightSpeedIn"><a href="#">Mr Ben Nguyen</a></li>
                        <li class="animated lightSpeedIn"><a href="#">Mr John Lee</a></li>
                        <li class="animated lightSpeedIn"><a href="#">Mr Robert Lamothe</a></li>
                        <li class="animated lightSpeedIn"><a href="#">Mr Bryan D.</a></li>
                        <li class="animated lightSpeedIn"><a href="#">Ms Shakira G.</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox-holder text-left">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredOne" name="check" />
                        <label for="squaredOne"><span>I Agree to the <strong>Terms &amp; Conditions</strong></span></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

php form is here

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "email@hotmail.com";

    $email_subject = "Rhien Centennial Comment Form";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We're sorry, but there's errors found with the form you submitted.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');        
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
      $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
      $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
      $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
      $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
      died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

The php isn't inline with the html form, but for some reason the php code won't work without last_name and telephone. So I just left it, as I don't know how to get it working without it.

Comment: Well, it's very possible. But all you have is an HTML form... No PHP anywhere

Comment: I will update it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden input field to your form and add an event handler to the dropdown (I.e. Onclick/onchange). Example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="email_to" name="email_to">

...

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById("email_to").value = "someone@somewhere.com">Someone</a>
```